# Form input type date-time returns a string instead of a date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

In [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h7y4RPOviX7_nzqWZRF2_eayzMda22X3wIyEXS7vXCM/edit?usp=sharing),

From the script editor we have an HTML form that submits dates and times into the sheet.

The purpose is to check with the calendar app if there is any events among the submitted time range.

The problem is that the calendar app is reading the submitted dates and times as a string/text, instead of dates and times and returns an error

> Cannot find method getEvents(string,string)

I manually modified the inputs from **2020-02-21T18:00** into **2020-02-21 18:00:00**, tested the code and it worked. So, I guess that the problem is with the format of the date-time values submitted by the form

The shared file is an editable version, feel free to edit and fix. Thanks in advance :)

#### Google Apps Script

```
function doPost (e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

  if (!e || !e.parameter) {
    return;
  }

  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10 * 1000);

  try {

    // Form response sheet
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    });
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);

    // Get all events for the time range
    var startTime = newRow[1];
    var endTime = newRow[2];
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("###");
    var allEvents = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
    if (allEvents.length > 0) {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify('Not Available. Thanks'))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    }else {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify('Available. Thanks'))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    };

  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<form name="Class1" id="Class1" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec" target="_blank" method="POST">

Start Date & Time
<input type="datetime-local" required name="Start Date & Time">

End Date & Time
<input type="datetime-local" required name="End Date & Time">

<button type="submit">Check</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I added your script from your shared Spreadsheet to your question. By this, users can see the script. At this time, I removed the personal information from the calendar ID and the endpoint of Web Apps. Could you please confirm it? If you are required to modify, please modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that in your script, the values of `startTime` and `endTime` are the string values of **ISO8601**. And at `getEvents(startTime, endTime)`, `startTime` and `endTime` are required to be the date object. So I think that `new Date()` can be used.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var allEvents = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
```

To:

```
var allEvents = cal.getEvents(new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime));
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected. Please be of careful this.**

#### References:

- [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [getEvents(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime)

If I misunderstood your question, and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks a million Tanaike. That is exactly what I needed. Very much appreciated

Comment: @Cen Eg Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.